# Persistence for cookies

Tags: cookies, python-2.7, mechanize

I am working with python mechanize on making a login script. I have read that the mechanize's Browser() object will handle with cookies automatically for further requests.
How can i make this cookie persistent ie save into a file so that I can load from that file later. 
My script is currently logging-in(using mechanize/HTML forms) to the website with Browser() object every time it is run.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the API docs for Mechanize at

http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html

there is some information regarding specifically what you're asking, specifically the `CookieJar` and `LWPCookieJar` materials.

From the docs:

*There are also some CookieJar subclasses which can store cookies in files and databases. FileCookieJar is the abstract class for CookieJars that can store cookies in disk files. LWPCookieJar saves cookies in a format compatible with the libwww-perl library. This class is convenient if you want to store cookies in a human-readable file:*

```
import mechanize
cj = mechanize.LWPCookieJar()
cj.revert("cookie3.txt")
opener = mechanize.build_opener(mechanize.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open("http://foobar.com/")
cj.save("cookie3.txt")
```

EDIT: Pseudo code for what is asked for in comments

- Attempt to load your CookieJar from file
- If successful, set your Browser() cookie jar to the loaded cookie jar
- Attempt to access the page normally
- Else if unsuccessful go through the pages until you reach a point where you have all of the cookies
- Save the cookies to the file using the LWPCookieJar();

Comment: Error at third line. No file named 'cookie3.txt'(i have tried to create an empty cookie3.txt file, didn't work). Also I need to work with `Browser()` methods like `open()`,`find_link()`, `click_link()`,.. by loading the saved cookie...

Comment: You got a 'No file named' error because it doesn't exist. The code I posted is an example of usage, not a 'plug this into your code'. As for using Browser, then just do so? You can call `Browser().set_cookie_jar(cj)` to set it's cookies. This wasn't the original question however, you should modify it if you are not looking how to persist your cookies.

Comment: I haven't got my answer.Maybe I will tell you what I need to do 1)visit the site 'http://m.mobile9.com/' on your web browser. you are visiting this site for first time from your browser(ie all your webbrowser cookies from this site should be cleared) 2)Since this is your first time the site will show you a phone chooser page 3)let us select a phone, say 'Nokia6300' 4)You will be redirected to the url 'http://gallery.mobile9.com/o/nokia+6300_409/' 5)next time you visit 'http://m.mobile9.com/' you willbe automatically redirected to url in step-4 6)This is what i want/can't select phone everytime

Comment: You have gotten an answer for the question you asked, specifically saving your cookies. `How can i make this cookie persistent ie save into a file so that I can load from that file later.` After receiving your error you did not continue debugging as to why it was a file not found (since you need to have the actual file saved before trying to access it). I'll update my answer with pseudo code for what you'd like to do.

Comment: Then I don't fully understand how this specific question you asked is not answered? Open a new question for your other problems, but it seems to me in terms of `save into a file so that I can load from that file later` is answered, based on what you just said.

Comment: of course your answer helped me a lot. I asked for `save into a file so that I can load from that file later` so that I can select the phone only once and save it to a file. next time i visit 'm.mobile9.com/' it will automatically redirected to my already selected phone page.